# How do I add fragrance when making homemade candles?

Tags: wax, candle-making

I am attempting to make homemade candles for Christmas this year and I want them to have a nice relaxing lavender smell to them. The first time around I used about 10 drops off lavender essential oils in 12 oz of hot wax, but that didn't seem to do the trick. The fragrance is barely there. Is there any way to do this with essential oils?

I would like to know how I can use essential oils to make a candle smell good while burning?

Comment: Are you asking how to add fragrance to candles or if it is possible to add fragrance to candles using essential oils?

Comment: Welcome to A&C Cory!  

What I am wondering because I am a novice to candle making. Someone might be able to elaborate to my comment. When you add the essential oils to the candle wax, it will take several days for the overall smell of the candle to develop. In the beginning the candle will have a slight scent, the longer it sits the more the scent develops. It can become unpleasant if too much oil is added, and then it will be too strong.

Comment: @Joachim I'm asking (and thus edited to my question to make it a bit more clear) how I can use essential oils to make candles smell good

Comment: @Lyssagal why does it begin to smell bad? Is this due to the wax reheating when the candle is burning? I really don't want to give bad smelling gifts

Comment: It isn't so much smell bad (like spoiled as an example) and more that the smell is too strong and it could be overwhelming to the nose if there is too much essential oil added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use essential oils to to make homemade candles. Make sure you add it into the wax mixture when creating it and never add it directly on the top of a pre-made candle because essential oils are flammable.

From my quick searches of 'essential oils for homemade candles' their recommended essential oil drops are between 30-45 drops. Then I do see blogs focused around aromatherapy suggesting 80-100 drops. 10 drops might not be enough. Trial and error are probably the best thing that could be done since it is several weeks before Christmas. It will give a couple weeks to try them out and see if it is the fragrance you are looking for.

In the blog by runtoradiance they mention about "flash points" related to high heat and soy candles, and how important it is to pick the right type of essential oil for diy scented candles. How hot and cold temperatures affect essential oils.

Also in the comments above it is going to take a couple weeks for the smell to fully develop in a home made candle. Just keep trying and see what is best scent wise to you.

Resources related to how much wax to add to home-made essential candles:
How to make essential oil candles: https://www.essentialoilhaven.com/how-to-make-candles-with-essential-oils/
Easy diy essential candles: https://www.runtoradiance.com/easy-diy-essential-oil-candles/
How hot and cold temps affect essential oils: https://www.theresaneoforthat.com/how-hot-and-cold-temperatures-affect-essential-oils/

Comment: 30-45 drops to how much wax?